# Does an INDEFINITE Timeline accumulate frames in memory for each keyframe?

Tags: javafx, timer

I'm trying to generate simple periodic events in JavaFX similar to the javax.swing.Timer.  It seems that javax.animation.Timer is the new way of doing this.  I am able to generate an event every 2 seconds with this code:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
        Duration.millis(2000),
        e -> iterate()));
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
```

It looks like I'm only creating one keyframe that should be re-evaluated every 2 seconds. But then there is [this mysterious warning from the Timeline API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html):

> Warning : A running Timeline is being referenced from the FX runtime.
>   Infinite Timeline might result in a memory leak if not stopped
>   properly. All the objects with animated properties would not be
>   garbage collected.

Is it safe to assume that this sample timeline will not accumulate memory since it does not access JavaFX properties?

Is it safe to assume that when this timeline is running it will not hold other objects with different animated properties in memory?

Comment: It means that the `Timeline` remains referenced as long as it is running, so any nodes referenced by it (e.g. accessed in your `iterate()` method) can't be garbage collected while the timeline is still running. What this essentially means is that if you remove the animated UI components from the scene graph (or, generally, if the objects you manipulate from the `Timeline` go out of scope), you should stop the `Timeline`.

Comment: Make that an answer and I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FX toolkit will keep a reference to any running animation. Thus if an animation runs indefinitely, via a call to `setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE)`, the toolkit will keep a reference to it until and unless `stop()` is called.

Of course, the timeline has a reference to all of its `KeyFrame`s, and the `KeyFrame`s have references to their event handlers, which in turn may keep references (typically to UI elements). Consequently, if an animation runs indefinitely, it will prevent garbage collection of any of the UI elements it animates, even if those elements are no longer displayed and are out of scope from the rest of your application.

So the warning you quote is advising that if you use indefinite animations, you must call `stop()` on those animations if you stop displaying the nodes that are being animated (or, more generally, allow the objects they reference to go out of scope). There is no "accumulation of `KeyFrame`s", but without calling `stop()` you may prevent garbage collection of UI elements you are no longer using.

Comment: And of course, as long as you keep a reference to the `Animation` yourself, it makes no difference whether you start or stop it. You must both stop it and stop using all references to it of your own for the `Animation` and all that it references to go away.

Comment: @JosiahYoder Correct: but in the code snippet you posted, you appear to create it only as a local variable.

Comment: Correct. In my case, it's a local variable that gets copied into some lambda expressions tied to the GUI. Since my GUI will maintain those lambda expressions, the `Animation` is maintained whether I stop it or not.

Comment: @JosiahYoder I think the use-case they're imagining is something like a splash screen, or perhaps custom dialog, with animations running. Once you close such a screen or dialog, then everything associated with it will be out of scope, but if there's an animation that isn't stopped the FX toolkit will keep a reference to the animation and consequently to the entire window and its scene graph. If you just have one window that is present for the entire lifecycle of the application, it doesn't much matter.